# Twitter Bootstrap + jQuery validation issue in IE 9

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, internet-explorer-9, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap css framework on a page which uses modal to show a login box(bootstrap-modal.js). In the login box I am using jquery really simple validation (jquery.rsv.js) for validating the email id and password. The problem is that the validation doesnt work inside the login modal box in IE 9. On the same page I have another form which is not in a modal and the validation works perfectly fine.

Below is my bootstrap modal form code :-

```
<div id="modal-from-login" class="modal hide fade">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
              <h3>Login for existing customers</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

    <form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="post" action="login/">

        <div class="clearfix"><label for="comments">Email ID:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="loginemail" /></div>
        <div class="clearfix"><label for="comments">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="loginpassword" />
    </div>
        </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" style="float:left;margin-left:130px;" name="login" id="login" value="Login" class="btn primary" />
    </div>

</form>
    </div>
```

This is the button code:-

```
<button class="btn primary" data-controls-modal="modal-from-login" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true" style="margin-top:5px;">Login</button>
```

The javascript code for validation:-

```
    
    function my_custom_function()
        {
```

if (document.getElementById("website").value){

        var url = document.getElementById("website").value;
        var test = /^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(url);

        var field = document.getElementById("website");

        if(test){
            return true;
        }else{
         return [[field, "Please enter a valid website."]];
        }
       }else{
        return true;
       }
    }
$(document).ready(function() {

    function loginComplete(){
        return true;
    }   



    $("#loginform").RSV({
          onCompleteHandler: loginComplete,
                rules: [
                        "required,loginemail,Please enter your email id.",
               "valid_email,loginemail,Please enter a valid email address.",
               "required,loginpassword,Please enter your password."
                       ]
        });

});
</script>

I am using jquery 1.4.2

What is the problem?? This code works fine in all other browsers even in IE8 the issue is there only in IE 9.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, why aren't you using jQuery?! Use
$("#website").val()
instead of
document.getElementById("website").value
You're also doing 3 lookups for the same thing in as many lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your code convention is terrible, making the reader crazy.

1. my first suggestion is that, yourself are always the reader of your code, for yourself's convenience, please make your code formatted(indent, naming convention etc). And agreed with  Synchro, I think in jQuery, you should prefer to use:

   $("#form_id")

   instead of:

   document.getElementById("form_id")
2. my second suggestion: make your problem more clearer. "The problem is that the validation doesnt work inside the login modal box in IE 9". there are many cases make it doesn't work. is there JS error? or is the form submitted successfully without field validated? did you keep your eyes on the IE9's developer tool's console? were there error messages when form is being submitted?
3. my third... question:  I saw you defined a custom function named: "my_custom_function()", but you didn't use it. see your code:

   You should insert this line of code into the array:

   rules: [
       // other validation rules...
       "function,my_custom_function"
   ]